# Working with Json in windows phone

Tags: json, web-services, windows-phone-8

I have some problems using Json in Windows phone projects.
The problem is that I really can't understand the mechanism of working with Json data , how to retrieve data from server and how to send data to the server.
I tried searching, googling and trying sample codes.
I knew that I'll use Newtonsoft and I tried using it but all I did was just copy and paste and can't understand how it works or how to use it .
Please help me to solve my problem .
P.S : I tried Newtonsoft Tutorial but did'n understand anything

Comment: Its answer is really broad.I suggest you go first implement things and make a sample project working. and then split each part like - json, json serializaion , json deserialixation, httpclient etc, You have do it by your own.

Comment: I don't know when to use serialize, deserialization, httpclient etc 
I need some links tutorials or books to learn from and understand

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-use-HttpClient-to-b9289836